# Match index.html or empty url end with regex

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check for a url ending of either:

```
http://www.site.com/html/
```

OR

```
http://www.site.com/html/index.html
```

So far I have this (with numerous attempts of moving the $ and /'s) but can seem to get it to work.

```
window.location.pathname.match(/index.html/|/^$z/))
```

Comment: Please clarify your question, do you want to match `index.html` or empty string if not present or you are trying to test the validity of a URL, where the URL can only end by `/` or `index.html`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
window.location.pathname.match(/\/$|index\.html/)
```

Will match the last / of the pathname, and also index.html

The first part of the regex "/$" escapes the forward slash, and the $ matches the last character of the string. So the way I read it is "The last character is a forwardslash"

The second part of the regex "index.html" matches index.html, but you have to escape the period because "." matches any character.

Heres a regular expression cheatsheet: http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/